# Ext.Window - remove rounded corners

Tags: extjs

**ExtJS 4.1**

How toremove rounded corners from Ext.Window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create another theme. This can be done with SASS, or you can overwrite the css.
I strongly advice sass though.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/theming

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could also use a floating panel, instead of a window.